# Local HTTP port forwarding based on url suffix

Tags: port-forwarding

I'm searching for a solution to locally forward webhook http post requests based on the url to which the request is sent.

For example: I have my http server on 192.168.1.1. on port 80. If an http request comes in to http://192.168.1.1:80/landing1/ i want the request to be forwarded to http://127.0.0.1:5001. If a request goes to http://192.168.1.1:80/landing2/ it shall be forwarded to http://127.0.0.1:5002 and so on.

The reason is that i use flask applications on the 500x ports, which handle these different webhook posts. However, the server that sends the http post requests has port restrictions, i.e. i am not allowed to have the webhook post requests send directly to the 500x ports and the allowed ports are insufficient to cover my flask applications.

I am using a popOS distro.

Thank you very much in advance.

Paul

Answer (score 1):

> forward [...] based on the url to which the request is sent.

That means you need a proxy (explicit or transparent), port forwarding by itself doesn't work. Because port forwarding is based on the numerical IP address, and DNS lookup happens way any packets with numerical IP addresses are produced, not to speak of the actual URL.

Basically any proxy will do, e.g. see this [list](https://www.tecmint.com/open-source-reverse-proxy-servers-for-linux/) (first google hit).

And the standard way to solve is to make the **proxy** listen on 192.168.1.1. on port 80. Then it's called a "frontend", and I'd recommend "nginx". And you move the original server that was on 192.168.1.1 somewhere else (e.g. also to 127.0.0.1, and forward the remaining requests to it).

Comment: Yes `nginx` will do that perfectly and fast.